# Populating span/div with database record

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I apologise if this comes across as really stupid. I have searched but can't seem to find an answer. I hope I can explain what it is I am trying to do.

I want to be able to query a database and if there is a record in it to show the record in the span/div or show a not found error message if there isn't.

I have a jquery check up and running to check if a username is in the database, what I want to know is how easy it would be to ammend this to pull all the data and show it in the span/div on the original page.

This is the jquery I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#username').keyup(username_check);
});

function username_check() {
    var username = $('#username').val();
    if (username == "" || username.length < 2) {
        $('#username').css('border', '1px #D5D5D5');
        $('#cross').hide();
        $('#tick').hide();
    } else {

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "check.php",
            data: 'username=' + username,
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                if (response == 1) {
                    $('#username').css('border', '2px #C33 solid');
                    $('#tick').hide();
                    $('#cross').fadeIn();
                } else {
                    $('#username').css('border', '2px #090 solid');
                    $('#cross').hide();
                    $('#tick').fadeIn();
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Can I do all this on the one page and query the db from the same page, instead of posting it to another page as I don't know how to get the results back to the calling page?

I hope I have explained what I want to do. Apologies if I haven't

Here is the PHP code:

```
$username = trim(strtolower($_POST['username'])); $username = mysql_escape_string($username); $query = "SELECT adbkid FROM person WHERE adbkid = '$username' LIMIT 1"; $result = mysql_query($query); $num = mysql_num_rows($result); echo $num; mysql_close()
```

Comment: Can you post some of PHP codes?

Comment: Actually, what is your question? What does not work for you? As far as your code shows, you know about AJAX which I say is already the solution. So what do you want to know?

Comment: He's outputting an integer response and wants to output a string and display it, I think.

Comment: Hi Gabriel, the php code is this:

    $username = trim(strtolower($_POST['username']));
$username = mysql_escape_string($username);

$query = "SELECT adbkid FROM person WHERE adbkid = '$username' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo $num;
mysql_close();

Comment: @Chris edit your question with your PHP code.

Comment: David, that is exactly what I am trying to do. I have tried used .val and .html but it won't show. Also, hakre, that was to show that I have tried some ajax/jquery and not asking for someone to outright answer it for me. Also, I don't know how to post the text value back. I am still fairly new to ajax/jquery

Comment: All you need to do is echo 'stringhere'; use .html for divs and .val for form elements

Answer (score 0):

You can output a string in PHP and then set that text value to an element with jQuery ( `$('#element').val(responseFromServer);`
or `$('#element').html(responseFromServer);`

Comment: So david, would I add $('#id of span').val(response) to the jquery. I tried that and it doesn't show anything. Would I need to do a while in the php page to show all the data? Sorry if I come across as dumb

Comment: you'd output whatever data you want with PHP, but you'd probably want to use the json_encode function so you can access it as any other JS object once you hit the success ajax callback

Answer (score 0):

You will normally send ajax requests to pages hosted on your server. So you can't directly access your database without going through your server. You'll need to write a function on your server that queries the database, and then call that function from javascript using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

check.php

```
$data = array();
$data['exists'] = false;

if(!isset($_POST['username'])) {
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit();
}

$username = mysql_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$query = "SELECT adbkid FROM person WHERE adbkid = '$username' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if(count($row) == 1) {
    $data = $row;
    $data['exists'] = true;
}

return json_encode($data);
```

from your jQuery:

```
success: function(response) {
    /**
     * For instance, for a table with id, username, password and email you have 
     * data.exists = true/false;
     * data.id = 1;
     * data.username = 'foo';
     * data.password = 'sample data password';
     * data.email = 'foo@bar.com';
     */
    if(response.exists === true) {
        $('#username').val(response.username);
        $('#email').val(response.email);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Gabriel, would it be the same way to do it if I am pulling a record that I know exists and am not checking for the existence of it. I was using the username as an example. Where you have $data = [..], would that be the query to get the data? Also, I have the form set as a post so would I just still use $_POST to see what the data is that is being posted over. Sorry for being somewhat dumb

Comment: Hello @Chris, I have done some edits (have not tested), which I think is working.

Comment: @Chris, if you want to return a response, or a message saying user exists, you can. I think you get the idea.

Comment: Hi Gabriel, many thanks for your effort. I have implemented you solution and it queries the database but always gives me a message saying that the username isn't found - even if I try one that is in there. I just don't know where I am going wrong

Comment: @Chris, do you have the online script, or know about Firebug? It is more easy to  deploy with one or both.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending back "1" send back a json response something like:

```
   /* record exists */
   {status:1, html:'server generated message about record'} 
   /* doesn't exist */
    {status:0}
```

This will allow you to still change css based on response data `status` value

Can use `$.post` ajax shorthand method:

```
$.post('check.php',{username: username},  function(response){
    var upDateElement=$('#spanID');

    if(response.status && response.status== 1){
        $('#username').css('border', '2px #C33 solid'); 
        $('#tick').hide();
        $('#cross').fadeIn();

        upDateElement.html( response.html)


    }else{
        $('#username').css('border', '2px #090 solid');
        $('#cross').hide();
        $('#tick').fadeIn();

        upDateElement.html('Message html for no record found')


    }
},'json')
```

Comment: thanks for your input here. The next question I have is how do you send the database record back to be shown in the spanID?

Also, as I said with Gabriel, it returns every response as 0 even if there is a corresponding record in the database. I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Any more pointers would be great